# NoClassDefFoundError while migrating spring 3 application from log4j1 to log4j2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jboss, log4j2

I am getting **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger** error while running my spring application war in jboss-6.4. I have added **log4j-api-2.18.0.jar** and **log4j-core-2.18.0.jar** in lib folders of application sub-modules and also updated the classpath. Its a ant based old application. Below is the stacktrace for the same :

```
18:39:01,261 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) Closing Hibernate SessionFactory
18:39:01,269 INFO  [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) closing
18:39:01,272 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSrcRepositoryService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
```

Does Spring 3 supports log4j2 or do I need to update to spring higher version or change anything to make this work ?

Comment: "I have added log4j-api-2.18.0.jar and log4j-core-2.18.0.jar in lib folders of application sub-modules and also updated the classpath" -> What do you mean by this?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins it's simple there is a parent application in which there are some sub modules so in all modules wherever the older dependency of log4j1 was there I removed that and added log4j2-api-2.18.0.jar and log4j-core-2.18.0.jar and update the classpath means when we import project in eclipse or sts there is a .classpath which have all the dependencies listed which are in the classpath so I mean that classpath .. hope this answers your question ..

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand the structure. Is this an EAR with modules? Like `EAR/some.war`, `EAR/some.jar`?

Comment: Yes its a war which contains all other sub-modules jars and third party jars

Comment: Ah okay so everything is in the `WAR/WEB-INF/lib`? Those are not sub-modules in the case of WildFly BTW.